# Newton-Raphson Method and Prove

Tags: analysis, newton-raphson

I have studying numerical analysis and came across this question.

Find the approximate value of $\sqrt5$ by using Newton-Raphson method. Take initial approximation as $2$ and $\epsilon = 10^{-6}$. You also prove that Newton-Raphson iteration scheme is second order convergent technique.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** *Let $x=\sqrt5$ then $f(x)=x^2-5=0$ The Newton–Raphson method for this equation is given by
 $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$.*

Comment: @Marceline Can you finish from here?